# 'Yes' to newsetter in checkout - store email and name in Subscriptions database

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have managed to add a checkbox for newsletter in my checkout by this article from Mageplaza: https://www.mageplaza.com/add-new-input-form-magento-2.html.

So how do I grab this information and store the user email and name in the newsletter subscriptions database, if the checkbox is ticked?

(pls bare with me - I am very new to customizing my site)